# C programming language in every operating systems book

Tags: c, system-calls

I am now reading two books:

- Tanenbaum - Modern Operating Systems
- Bach - The Design of the UNIX Operating System

and I wonder why do they still mention programs written in C and functions from C libraries (mostly system calls) in both books? It would not bother me if it was mentioned somewhere in the book - why they use C. Maybe it was mentioned but I didn't see it there.

Also in Java you can open file, write bytes into it, read bytes from it etc. so why C is mentioned there?

Also I would like to know form you guys, why there are manual pages about C functions in UNIX and UNIX-like systems. I have been using them since I started actively programming in C - it was about 2 years ago. I every time took these things as facts. But now I am beginning to ask WHY about them.

Comment: Why does *The Design of the UNIX Operating System* mention C‽

Comment: @MichaelHomer Why do The Design of the UNIX Operating System and Modern Operating Systems mention functions from C libraries.

Comment: The question could be rephrased as why OSes are mostly written in C. Notice that it would be difficult to write a garbage collector in Java.

Comment: The existing answer explains this in terms of the dates when the books were published versus the dates when the Java language was invented.  Clearly an answer that is _not based upon opinions at all_ is quite possible.

Comment: NOT opinion based, and it is a *VERY* important thing. The fun part is that practically ALL OS-es have a C interface on their lowest programmable level, WHY it happened so, it would be a *VERY IMPORTANT* thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why "C language" and "C libraries" are mentioned in this 2 Books, is simply because Unix was written in C.

Prof. Tanenbaum designed "Minix" which is also written in C.

In 1972 where Unix was create, there was no JAVA existing.

Comment: Java was not existing in that time, that's right. But why Java calls were not mentioned in Tannenbaum's book? Or calls of any other programming language? So the only answer for that is because Unix was written in C, right?

Comment: If i am not wrong, the Book you mentioned from Prof. Tanennbaum is from 1988 +- .
Java 1.0 was released in 1995. 

Tanenbaum had no reason talking about Java ..

Comment: You are right but it had several releases since that time. I think the newest one is from 2015.

Comment: Again, he was talking about "Modern Operating System"  and not "Modern Languages".

Java is not the right language to write OS with  it, since JAVA libs are partiyally written in C.

Comment: You still did not give me the answer. So when we are talking about operating systems, C is mentioned there because C is the most suitable language for writing operating systems?

Comment: yes, correct.
C is the most suitable language for writing OS.  We also should not forget Assembler :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62907/discussion-between-vafa-and-scarface).

Comment: @Vafa wasn't Solaris written in Java?

Comment: @ivanivan wiki says Solaris was written in C and C++ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29